# Eclipse debugging is not working

Tags: eclipse, debugging

[image]

```
 Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600
```

I put some breakpoints in this first picture:

[image: Breakpoints]

After that, i clicked the bug symbol to start debug mode:

[image: debug mode]

But the application started as if it is in normal run mode. And as you can see in 2. picture, those buttons can not be clicked (next step, step into).

I was using kepler, it was same so i downloaded luna but it is still same. I could use debug mode 5-6 months ago. I did not use eclipse since that time and did not change anything.

Comment: WTFFFF?? unbelievable!

Answer (score 8):

All your breakpoints are disabled because you have "Skip all Breakpoints" enabled. You can recognize this by the strike-trough breakpoint icon:

[image]

Enable your breakpoints again by clicking the icon in the very top left of your first screenshot:

[image]

This will turn the "Skip all Breakpoints" setting off again and your program can be debugged as expected. More on this in the [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-skipall_viewaction.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Do you

- try Debug start?
- use Debug on the right program?

It looks like the breakpoint was not catched...